# Is there any way to examine add-on using the js console in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I recently wrote a chrome extension and have been trying to port it into Firefox.

In chrome, you could use the full JS console to examine and mess with your (under development) extension, making bugfixing easy. Firefox (and firebug) don't seem to offer the same functionality.

Here's my code so far:

main.js:

```
var widgets = require("sdk/widget");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

var bmpanel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  width: 450,
  height: 300,
  contentURL: data.url("bookmarklet.html"),
  // contentScriptFile: data.url("get-text.js")
});

var widget2 = require("sdk/widget").Widget({
  id: "my-widget",
  label: "Add to site!",
  contentURL: "icon.png",
  panel: bmpanel
});
```

bookmarklet.html is a simple page with some inline javascript (references, so it plays nice with chrome).

I'm using cfx so I can develop locally and reuse files, but there's a chance this isn't the best way to go about it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks a bunch!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Development_extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ctll+alt+j and use console.error() instead console.log. Bug at SDK 1.14